# How to include third party jars while running a java program

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

A very noob question.
I have a java class

```
package org.foobar;
import thirdparty_jar1;
import thirdparty_jar2;

public class FooBar{
  public static void main(String[] args){
   // some code
 }
}
```

I use eclipse as my ide and I added these thirdparty jar 1 and jar 2 in its build path. and then I proceeded to export the jar.
Now I have a `foobar.jar` file and now I want to run it..

I did `java -cp /path/to/foobar.jar org.foobar.FooBar`

but it complains about missing third party libraries.
How do i run my jar (or probably build a fat jar) . I just want to run my program from command line.
Thanks

Comment: You need to set the class path in the jar files manifest to include the paths to the dependencies.

Comment: When exporting, you can include required libraries, outside, inside the generated jar. I recommend you to _play_ with the options.

Answer (score 1):

A jar has a manifest file called MANIFEST.MF, under the folder META-INF. This contains details about the jar file, the main class etc. Eclipse creates one by default, you can modify that or specify your own manifest file.

See `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html` and [Understanding the Default Manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html).

To add libraries to the classpath, you need to add the jar files' path to the manifest file, like this:

```
Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name
```

See [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Maven, you can add this to your pom.xml file. This will create an additional "fat" jar whenever you build with Maven. It goes in the 'build.plugins' section:

```
<build>
    <plugins>

        ...

        <!--
            The plugin below creates an additional, executable JAR with all dependencies
            included in it.
        -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attached</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${package}.FooBar</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        ...

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that you are using Eclipse, did you know you can export a runnable JAR *and* all its dependecies via the IDE?  Right-click on your project and select Export.  Search for "Runnable JAR".  You should see this:

[image]

Now you have a few options:

> Extract required libraries into generated JAR.

This will unpack the third party JARs and repack them, along with your class, into a single JAR.

> Package required libraries into generated JAR.

This will include the third party JARs into your JAR, as well as some special Eclipse magic to unpack them when needed.

> Copy required libraries into a sub-folder

This will copy the third party JARs into a folder and then update the manifest of your JAR, adding the third-party JAR relative file references to your classpath.